# Swift ++ & -- deprecated. Alternatives for a loop

Tags: swift, loops

++ and -- has been deprecated in swift as of the latest release and will be removed in Swift 3.

I have this code that is currently working that I want to update, but I am not sure how to rewrite it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
for var i = 2; i <= remarkIndex; ++i {
    if containsWind(metarArray[i]) {
        metarDict.updateValue(metarArray[i], forKey: "winds")
    }
}
```

I realize there's a different way Swift likes to make loops, but I am inexperienced with it. When I wrote all of this code, I just used the C++ way I was used to. Looking to have an example I understand that I can apply across my code.

Comment: Will that increment the value of i, and then return the incremented value?

Comment: `metarArray[2...remarkIndex].filter { containsWind($0) }.forEach { metarDict.updateValue($0, forKey: "winds" }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
for i in 2...remarkIndex
```

This is what you should always have been doing anyway.

However, since the only thing you want to do with `i` is to index into `metarArray`, it would be even better to cycle thru `metarArray` *itself*:

```
for item in metarArray[2...remarkIndex]
```

No index required!

Comment: Thanks for the short answer that gets right to the point. I am learning! Huzzah.

Comment: But even better, since you only want to work with `metarArray[i]`, would have been to cycle through `metarArray` _itself_. Indexing successively into an array is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Removing the outer loop does make a lot of sense now that you mention it. I appreciate that comment.

Comment: Also the fact that you want to start at index 2 has a bad smell. But that's another issue.

Comment: Agree, the only reason that is there is the formatted data is always beginning at position 2 from the govt wind reports. Thanks for all of these replies, I am still learning so it is a huge help.

Comment: See my revised answer. You can slice out the desired section of the array and just cycle thru the _items_ of the slice. No indexing required!

Comment: Remark: In OP's code, `i == remarkIndex` is *included* in the loop, so it should be `2 ... remarkIndex`.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR I slept thru it... :)

Comment: You can even use `where containsWind(item)`

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness, let's show a more functional approach for the inner block, too:

```
metarArray[2...remarkIndex]
   .filter(containsWind)
   .forEach { metarDict.updateValue($0, forKey: "winds") }
```

Comment: Oh my this is elegant and looks much less buggy. Will need to sit down and learn these syntax options. Thanks so much for your post.

Comment: This is certainly the Swiftiest way, but note that it entails an extra expense, as we must cycle through the slice _twice_. In your actual code, that expense is likely to be negligible, however.

Comment: @matt I completely agree that functional approach is not always the best approach.

Comment: But it is prettiest!